# Animation in changing LayoutParams in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, layoutparams

In my app there is a LinearLayout which has 0 Layout height. When I click the button this layout height should be LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT. This is the code I use in onclicklistner.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
slider.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

I want to animate this. How can I set animation to slider.

Comment: do you want animation on slider?

Comment: @NixitPatel: You want to implement the slider animation ???

Comment: @iDroid Explorer Yes I need to omplement slider animation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to implement the slider animation for your layout then see [this demo](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/).

**UPDATED**

Also see http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html

Hope it will help you.

If not then let me know.

Thanks.
Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 25):

I think you just want to animate a view from 0 height to its final height, you can do this with a custom Animation:

```
public class ShowAnim extends Animation {
    int targetHeight;
    View view;

    public ShowAnim(View view, int targetHeight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
            int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And do this in your code to start the animation:

```
Animation ani = new ShowAnim(headerView, 100/* target layout height */);
ani.setDuration(2000/* animation time */);
headerView.startAnimation(ani);
```

Comment: How do you do this without it starting at a height of zero every time?  If I do this once with a target layout height of 100, and then again with a target layout time of 200, I want it to go from 0 -> 100 and then 100 -> 200.

Comment: If you want to go from 100 -> 200, then just modify this line `view.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);` to something like `view.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight /*100 in your case*/ + (int) (targetHeight/*200 in your case*/-initialHeight * interpolatedTime);`

Comment: One thing that does not work is nothing happens when the initialHeight is 0.  There is no visual change at all.

Comment: There is also 1 problem with your previous response.  The order-of-operations is incorrect.  You must put parenthesis around `targetHeight - initialHeight` so the `* interpolatedTime` is applied after.

Comment: It's just quick psudo code to get things started, please adapt it to your own needs

Comment: @Andrew I found out that if you want animation to start not from zero you must specify height of params as follwoing: `view.getLayoutParams().height = (originalHeight*2) + (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);`. By `multiply originalHeight with 2` and add it to targetHeight which is multiply with interpolatedTime, it works for me.

Comment: What's the point of overriding `initialize()` if you're just going to pass all the parameters to `super.intialize()`?

Comment: @Nate in many situations you'd need to do some initialization/calculation in initialize(...) to set up for the coming animation. So while in this particular example no customization is done, the method was overridden so that people know this method exists as a customization point.

Comment: I had something similar implemented for a sliding animation. This works pretty well until you have another sliding animation nested within. Since the parent doesn't wrap_content then it fails to expand with the child view.

Answer (score 4):

use animateLayoutChanges xml and enableTransitionType in java or kotlin

**1. add animateLayoutChanges to root layout xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**2. in java**

```
LayoutTransition layoutTransition = mainLinearLayout.layoutTransition;
layoutTransition.setDuration(5000); // Change duration
layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

editText.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; // you can set number, example: 300

editText.requestLayout();
```

**3.in kotlin**

```
 val layoutTransition = mainLinearLayout.layoutTransition
 layoutTransition.setDuration(5000) // Change duration
 layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)

 editText.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT // you can set number, example: 300 

 editText.requestLayout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we have the layout transitions in android since JELLYBEAN we can use that instead of using the animation object.

The article below explains it in detail.
https://proandroiddev.com/the-little-secret-of-android-animatelayoutchanges-e4caab2fddec

In short we would only need this code -

```
tView.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
tView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Here lp would be the layout params

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newHeight);
```

One more thing to add would be to add this line in the layout file, to the layout that would be doing the transition.

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate change in Layout params of a Linear layout and its child you can use ***LayoutTransition***.

Its important that you define and attach transition to Linear layout parent  for eg:           `llRoot.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition)` in below code snippet before c hanging LayoutParams of child.

Support for [LayoutTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition) is above Android JellyBean

```
   private var AnimationDuration = 1100f


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private fun fadeOutControls() {
        var layoutTransition = LayoutTransition()
        layoutTransition.setDuration(AnimationDuration.toLong()) // Change duration

        layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
        layoutTransition.addTransitionListener(object : LayoutTransition.TransitionListener {
            override fun startTransition(transition: LayoutTransition, container: ViewGroup, view: View, transitionType: Int) {

            }

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            override fun endTransition(transition: LayoutTransition, container: ViewGroup, view: View, transitionType: Int) {
                //Change this line of code to below one
                transition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)
            }
        })

        // set transition to Linear layout
        llRoot.setLayoutTransition(layoutTransition)


         // change Layout params of child now to animate Transition
        val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        lp.weight = 10f
        mediaRoot.setLayoutParams(lp)

        leftControl.visibility = View.GONE
        rightControl.visibility = View.GONE
    }
```