# android apply transformation animation ignoring duration

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to set up some custom progress bar animation similarly to the way I have set it up in xCode.

In xCode I can use block code to set up an animation like this

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^(void)
         {
             imgView_p.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             //Do something in here

         }];
```

So I can take an imageView and just expand its frame to whatever I want, and it will animate to that new frame over the course of the duration I have passed in.

In Android I found this

```
Animation a = new Animation()
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) 
                        {
                             animateMe.getLayoutParams().height = 300;
                             animateMe.requestLayout();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                            return true;
                        }
                    };
                    a.setDuration(3000);
                    animateMe.setAnimation(a);
```

Basically this is a vertical bar, that will increase in height over the course of 3 seconds. However it is ignoring the setDuration(3000) and the animation just applies instantly which is really annoying. I know I must be missing something but I can't see what, would anyone else be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally back and I managed to find this link

[Animation in changing LayoutParams in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695981/animation-in-changing-layoutparams-in-linearlayout)

Using this guys animation class he created, it seems to work perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`.setStartOffset(3000)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset%28long%29). This will add a delay of 3000 milliseconds before your animation starts.

You start the Animation by calling `startAnimation(a)`, not by calling `setAnimation(a)`.

Comment: I have tried offSet but it doesn't do anything. And all that would do would delay the start of the animation, I want the actual animation to occur over the place of 3 seconds

Comment: @AdamM use `startAnimation`. I added it to my answer.

Comment: I tried adding startAnimation now as well, same thing. I am running on Jelly bean 4.2 on Nexus 4, would that have any affect on it?

Comment: @AdamM I would rebuild the whole project and try again. `Project` -> `Clean`.

Comment: Tried cleaning and even creating new project, animation is still happening instantly :@

Answer (score 0):

It is because you just set the final height of the view in the applyTransformation method.
You should use the interpolated time and make calculations. Lets say

```
(just a random silly way, do as you wish)
float h = currentHeight + interpolatedTime;
animateMe.getLayoutParams().height = (int) h;
animateMe.requestLayout();
```

So that, you will increase the height with the defined duration.

Comment: Tried that, same thing happening, instant animation

Comment: Have you tried ObjectAnimator class, basic scaling / translate ?             imageV.animate().scaleX(2).setDuration(1000);

Comment: Will have to try when I get back, away for few days as of tomorrow and only have access to the mac when I am in work

Comment: ObjectAnimator requires API 11 min, and my App min target is API 10