# setDuration not working in Animation class

Tags: android

I'm trying to animate the height of a ConstraintLayout using the Animation class, and the setDuration method doesn't seem to be working. The height is just instantly changed to the desired height value. I've seen posts about animations being disabled in the developer options, but that's not the problem, it's set to 1x. Anyway, code is below:

```
    public static void scaleUp() {

    Animation animation = new Animation() {

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) profileLayout.getLayoutParams();

            // modify your layout params here
            params.height = 10;

            profileLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        }
    };

        animation.setDuration(300); // in ms
        profileLayout.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of `params.height = 10;` use `params.height = (int)(10.0 * interpolatedTime)`.
2. Append `profileLayout.requestLayout();` at the end of your `applyTransformation` method. This is used to update the layout on a screen.

Comment: Getting some interesting results with this, its at least animating now. I think I should be all set!

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solutions:

1. [Answered Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704820/6552901)
2. [Medium Article About Animating](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/android-how-to-change-the-height-of-a-view-using-animation-9aad81369781)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I should of decreased the speed just to remove that as a possible solution. I've tried setting it to multiple seconds and no changes. I think the medium article looks really promising, but I'm getting an error "Lambda expressions are not supported at language level '7'" on the code: `slideAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation1 -> { Integer value = (Integer) animation1.getAnimatedValue(); view.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue(); view.requestLayout(); });`

Comment: Welcome, for the "Lambda expressions are not supported at language level '7'" do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704620/6552901